# How to create a simple iOS type Table View using HTML / Twitter Bootstrap / Jquery Mobile etc

Tags: javascript, html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I know Objective-C, but I am very new to HTML/jQuery/JS.

I want to create a Table view using these.

Can anyone assist me by showing me how to do this? Although I was able to create a static Table view using below code.

I am now stuck unsure of how to fill it with an Array.

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Twitter Bootstrap : Grids  using Bootstrap </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <style>
        .demog  {
            background:#444;
            color:#ffffff;
            padding:10px;
            height:80px;
            margin-left: 0 ;
            margin-bottom:1px;
            text-align:left;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="table">
            <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="True" data-back-btn-text="Return">
                <h1>Table</h1>
                <a href="dashboard.html" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"
                data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
                <div class="bootstrap-demo">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">value 1   <br><br>Thdepiof fu utoiurotiurotpu oiturou</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 2</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 3</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 4</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 5</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 6</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 7</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 8</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 9</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 10</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 11</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="demog">Value 12</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the sample output you need

Comment: If possible for you, kindly run the above code. I need same Output as above code gives. But with an array. Like in My above code i have given VALUE 1, VALUE 2.... UPTO VALUE12 staticly. I want to do this with an array

Comment: hmm.. see in view page if you have server side variable containing an array then you can apply looping(like foreach) for dynamically creating new div's. If you want I can give you sample php code.

Answer (score 0):

For JQuery, a dynamic tableview implementation is pretty straightforward. You can replace your 'row' div with something like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="itemslist" data-autodividers="true">
</ul>
```

where the last attribute is optional if you don't want sub-headers.

Then you can populate the list with javascript like this, where 'data' is a JSON array of 'item' objects:

```
function updateList(data, listId, target) {
    // called to populate list    
    $(listId).empty();
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $(listId).append('<li><a href="' +target+ '" id="' + item.title + '"><h3>' + item.title + '</h3></a></li>');
    });
    $(listId).listview().listview('refresh');
}
```

The list can be populated on any of the page events (e.g. pageinit, pageshow, pagebeforeshow), as in the below example. Note that some page events are deprecated in JQuery Mobile 1.5, in favor of pagecontainer events.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#main', function(){

    updateList(allitems, '#itemslist', '#itemdetail');

    $('#itemslist').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        // store selected item into global variable for use on detail page
        curItem = this.id;
    });

});
```

Here's a complete working example, with data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

        <!-- JQuery dependencies -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

        <script>

              var allitems = [ 
              {"title":"first item",
              "description":""
              },
              {"title":"second item",
              "description":""
              },
              {"title":"third item",
              "description":""
              },
              {"title":"fourth item",
              "description":""
              }
              ];

          $(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){

              updateList(allitems, '#itemslist', '#itemdetail');

              $('#itemslist').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
                  // store selected item into global variable for use on detail page
                  curItem = this.id;
              });

          });

          function updateList(data, listId, target) {
            // called to populate list    
            $(listId).empty();
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                $(listId).append('<li><a href="' +target+ '" id="' + item.title + '"><h3>' + item.title + '</h3></a></li>');
            });
            $(listId).listview().listview('refresh');
          }
        </script>

        <title>List demo</title>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>List demo</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <div>
                  <ul data-role="listview" id="itemslist">
                  </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I am very much new to this. Can you please give me the whole code how to call updateList.